# Draw a terrain with python?

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, plot, rendering

I have a numpy 2d-array representing the geometrical height of a specific area where a street will be build. I can visualize this using `scipy.misc.toimage`. However I would like to get a simple 3D view of the area. Is there a simple way to plot or render this data as an 3d-image?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps use matplotlib's [plot_surface](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots) or [plot_wireframe](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#wireframe-plots):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

np.random.seed(1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
N = 100
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(N), np.arange(N))
heights = np.sin(2*np.pi*np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2)/N)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, heights, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

These functions require three 2D-arrays: X, Y, Z.
You have the heights, `Z`. To generate the standard `X` and `Y` locations associated with those `Z`s, you could use `np.meshgrid`.